# Where to store SQL code for a C++ application?

Tags: c++, sql

We have a C++ application that utilizes some basic APIs to send raw queries to a MS SQL Server. Scattered through the various translation units in our program, we have simple 1-2 line queries as C++ strings, and every now and then you'll see more complex queries that can be over 20 lines.

I can't help but think that the larger queries, specifically the 20+ line ones, should not be embedded in C++ code as constant strings. I want to propose pulling these out into separate text files that are loaded on-demand by the C++ application, however I'm not sure if this is the best approach.

What design choices are typical for situations like this? I definitely feel there needs to be improvement, I just don't know if moving the SQL queries out into data files (text files) is the best idea.

Comment: Stored Procedures?  Treat your DB like a remote object with it's own methods?

Comment: What exactly do you hope to gain by separating them? Do they (for example) change frequently compared to the code that loads/executes them? Could they, perhaps, be turned into stored procedures that would be stored in the database itself? Are their details closely related to the surrounding code, or can that code reasonably treat them as relatively abstract black boxes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a DAL (Data Access Layer).

It would be the API that the rest of the program talks to.  Then you can mess around and try anything and everything (Stored procedures, caching, etc.) without disturbing the main program.

Answer (score 1):

Move them into their own files, or even into their own stored procedures. Queries embedded in the application cannot be changed without a recompile, and depending on your release procedures, that could severely impair your ability to respond to emergencies or deploy hot fixes. You could alter your app to cache the file contents, if you go down that road, and even periodically check the files for updates.

Answer (score 1):

the best "design choice" - for many different reasons - is to use MSSQL stored procedures whenever/wherever possible.

I've seen code that segregates SQL queries into a common module, but I don't think there's much benefit to a common "queries module" (or a standalone text file) over having the SQL queries spelled out as string literals in the module that's calling them.

Stored procedures, on the other hand, increase modularity, enhance security, and can vastly improve performance.

IMHO...

Answer (score 1):

I would leave the SQL embedded in the C++ functions that use it: it will be easier to read and understand what the code does.

If you have SQL queries scattered around your code I'd say that there is some problem with the overall structure of the classes you are using: you should have some (or even just one) 'low level' classes that handle the interaction with the database, and the rest of the code uses these classes.

I personally don't like using stored procedure: if you have to support a different database server the porting will be a pain, I never saw that much of a performance improvement and to understand what the code does you have to jump back and forth between the stored procedures and the C++.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends, here are some notes:

1) If all your sql code resides in the application, then your application is pretty much self contained in terms of logic. This is good as you have done in the current application. In terms of speed, this can be a little slower as SQL will need to be parsed when when you run these queries(also depends if you used Prepared statements,etc which can speed it up).

2) The second approach is to put all SQL logic as stored procedures on the server. This is a very much preferred approach for even small SQL queries whether one line or not. You just build a DAL layer. In terms of performance this is very good, however the logic lives in two different systems, your C++ app and the SQL server. You will quite likely need to build a small utility application that can translate the stored procedures input and output to template code (be it C++ or any other) to make your life easier.

3) A mixed approach with the above two. I would not recommend this route.

Answer (score 0):

You need to think about how these queries are likely to change over time, and compare it to how the related C++ code is likely to change.  If the queries are relatively independent of the code, and have a higher likelihood of change, then I would either load them at runtime from separate files, or use stored procedures instead.  That approach allows for changing the queries without recompiling the C++ code.  On the other hand, if the queries are highly coupled to the C++ code, making a change in one likely to accompany a change in the other, I would keep the queries in the code.  This approach makes a change more localized and less error prone.